# Does there exist at least four elements in $\operatorname{SL}(2,q)$ of different order?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

### The Question:

> In $\operatorname{SL}(2,q)$, does there always exist at least four elements of distinct order?

### Thoughts:

I have strong reasons to suspect that this is true.

The order of $\operatorname{SL}(2,q)$ is $(q-1)q(q+1)$, so is a multiple six. Cauchy's theorem implies elements $g,h$ of order two and three, respectively. There's the identity element.  Also, since $-I$ and $h$ commute, when $q$ is odd, $|-Ih|=6$.

So what I really need is the $q$ even case.

I've spent far too long on this but I need it for my dissertation.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Note that if $q>3$, so that $q-1>2$, then there has to be a prime that divides $q+1$ but not $q-1$, and thus you can get element of three distinct prime orders.

Comment: Why is that prime not also $3$, @SteveD?

Comment: If every prime dividing $q+1$ also divided $q-1$, then all of those primes would need to divide $$gcd(q-1,q+1)\le 2$$

Comment: Sorry I realize I'm making this confusing, because I was only thinking of $q$ a power of 2 originally. So here's the more general statement: if the set of primes dividing $q-1$ and $q+1$ are the same, then both must be a power of $2$, so that $q=3$. We also want $q>2$ so that there is in fact _some_ prime dividing $q-1$.

Comment: *Now* it makes sense, @SteveD. Thank you! I should have realised.  That's quite elegant, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false for $q=2$ but true otherwise: For $q=2$ you can just directly check that $\mathrm{SL}_2(2)\simeq S_3$ which only has elements of orders 1,2 and 3.

For $q\geq 8$, there are always elements $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}_q^\times$ of some multiplicative order other than 1, 2 or 3, so that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & 0 \newline 0 & \alpha^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$ gives the last element.

For the remaining case $q=4$, the group has order $60$ and so has elements of order 5 as well.

Comment: Thank you.  Thankfully, $S_3$ is negligible to my ideas thus far.

Answer (score 2):

As $\mathrm{SL}(2,2)\cong S_3$, it doesn't contain elements besides ones of oders $1,2,$ and $3$. In particular your claim is false for $q=2$. However for $q=2^n$ for $n>1$ you can prove the existence of an element of order other than $1,2,$ or $3$ as follows:

If $n>1$ view $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ as $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(P)$ for some irreducible degree $n$ polynomial $P$. Now the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}x&x+1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}(2,2^n)$$ can be checked to have unequal to the identity matrix first, second, and third powers and thus be of order exceeding $3$.